# How to convert NVarchar date time to date time format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to convert this date to date time format

```
20180206 00:00
```

or

```
20180206 00:00
```

Comment: What's wrong with aptly named `CONVERT` function?

Comment: Also, are you *really* using SQL Server 2008? It's been out of support for some 18~ months now.

Comment: Side note, as well, all but one of your visible questions have a score of <=0 , and half of those visible questions have a negative score. I suggest you seriously consider improving the quality of your questions as you are very likely close to a question ban.

Answer (score 4):

```
 SELECT CAST('20180206 00:00' AS DATETIME)
```

Could you please try this